# Is it possible to set the isolation level?

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent

Is there a field in the [persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) config where I can set the desired isolation level for the session?

Or alternatively, is it possible to execute SQL code when the connection is established and before any transactions run? That would allow me to

```
set session transaction isolation level ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [createSqlPool](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/persistent/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v%3acreateSqlPool) is used by the scaffolding to create your connection pool. It takes as its first argument an `IO Connection` action. If you're using PostgreSQL, you can create a `Connection` value via [openSimpleConn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-postgresql-1.3.1/docs/Database-Persist-Postgresql.html#v%3aopenSimpleConn). Putting that together, you can:

- Create a postgresql-simple connection.
- Set the transaction level.
- Call openSimpleConn

If you write a function that does that and pass that to `createSqlPool`, you should get the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I cannot find `createSqlPool` anywhere in the scaffolded site. I'm still using yesod 1.2.2, maybe this was added in a later version?

Comment: Regardless of which exact function it is, somewhere in your application.hs is code to create a connection pool.

Comment: Finally found it: `makeFoundation` creates a `dbconf`. For MySQL one can add an `InitCommand` to the connection options to set the isolation level.